# Connect to python server using socket from C# and receive data

Tags: python, c#, sockets, connection, client

I have a program in python named server.py and I want to send multiple messages to client.cs using a socket, and use them while python program is still running.
I tried before in py (server) to py (client) and it works, but when I try py (server) to C# (client) I get multiple exceptions.

This is server.py:

```
import socket
import time
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 7634

s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(1)

con, addr = s.accept()
print("Connected with: ", addr)


message = 1800

while message <= 2000:

    con.send(str(message).encode())
    message += 1
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

Client.py:

```
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

host = socket.gethostname()
port = 7634

s.connect((host, port))

message = 1800

while message <= 2000:
    
    message = int(s_messg.decode())
    print(message, "\n")
```

As I said before this works fine

Sending 1800 and instantly receiving 1800
Sending 1801 and instantly receiving 1801
...
Sending 2000 and instantly receiving 2000

I saw C# client code from Microsoft doc, but as I said before I get multiple exceptions:
SocketException: System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException
It says that the connection could not be established.

```
            try
            {
                server = "127.0.0.1";

                Int32 port = 7634;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

     
                Byte []data = new Byte[256];

                // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);

                // Close everything.
                stream.Close();
                client.Close();
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
```

Comment: Works for me, in the sense that it is completes without throwing an exception. I'm not sure what you're trying to do but the client is going to read whatever is available from the server and then exit. Since the server waits 0.1 seconds between sends that means the client will almost always read "1800" and then exit.

Comment: I tried this, now it works
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/synchronous-client-socket-example